# Efficiency: std::array vs. std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, std

I'm using `std::vector` here in this line:

```
std::vector<bool> visited(length);
```

to solve [a LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game-iv/):

> Given an array of integers arr, you are initially positioned at the
> first index of the array.
>
> In one step you can jump from index i to index:
>
> - i + 1 where: i + 1 < arr.length.
> - i - 1 where: i - 1 >= 0.
> - j where: arr[i] == arr[j] and i != j.
>
> Return the minimum number of steps to reach the last index of the
> array.
>
> Notice that you can not jump outside of the array at any time.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> Input: arr = [100,-23,-23,404,100,23,23,23,3,404]
> Output: 3
> Explanation: You need three jumps from index 0 --> 4 --> 3 --> 9.
>
> #### Note that index 9 is the last index of the array.
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> 1 <= arr.length <= 5 * 10^4
> -10^8 <= arr[i] <= 10^8

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>

class Solution {
public:
    int minJumps(const std::vector<int>& nums) {
        int length = nums.size();
        std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> value_indices;

        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
            value_indices[nums[index]].push_back(index);
        }

        std::vector<bool> visited(length);
        visited[0] = true;
        std::queue<int> queue;
        queue.push(0);
        int min_steps = 0;

        while (!queue.empty()) {
            for (int size = queue.size(); size > 0; size--) {
                int index = queue.front();
                queue.pop();

                if (index == length - 1) {
                    return min_steps;
                }

                std::vector<int>& next_jumps = value_indices[nums[index]];
                next_jumps.push_back(index - 1);
                next_jumps.push_back(index + 1);

                for (int jump : next_jumps) {
                    if (jump > -1 && jump < length && !visited[jump]) {
                        visited[jump] = true;
                        queue.push(jump);
                    }
                }

                next_jumps.clear();
            }

            min_steps++;
        }

        return 0;
    }
};
```

It seems `std::array` might be more efficient, but I'm not sure. Should I use `std::array` and how would you suggest to do so? Is there anything else that would make this Solution more efficient?

Comment: `std::array` needs to know the size at compile time. `length` is not known at compile time.

Comment: Do note that `std::vector<bool>` is basically a dynamic bitset.  This means all access is going to involve bitwise operations to write or read the single bit that needs to be changed.

Comment: @NathanOliver only for implementations that specialize `vector<bool>` to store `bool` values in bits to save memory.  Not all implementations do that.  In cases where it is, one could consider using `std::bitset` or `boost::dynamic_bitset` as an alternative instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau True, but all the major vendors do this so unless the OP is using something special it will most likely be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a `std::array` is just a fancy c++ wrapper for an object that is the same as a normal C array. And just like a C array, the size needs to be known beforehand. If an array is allocated in a function it goes on the stack just like a C array. If it is allocated as part of a class the storage for the array is a simple offset from the beginning of the class.

For this reason, if you need to access the a cell in the array memory for it is close and therefore likely to be in the cache.

a `std::vector` has dynamic storage, this means the storage is allocated on the heap (using `new` or similar). So if you are working on the stack, the storage is likely to be far away and is more likely to not be in the cache so in that sense might be slower.

On the otherhand you do not need to know how big a `std::vector` will be. When adding to a vector when it runs out of previously allocated storage, it moves the data to a larger storage location. So when adding, to avoid constantly resizing, you can `reserve` space up front to speed things up.

Since storage is non-local, a `std::vector` will move better than a `std::array`. Both `std::array` and `std::vector` will always store data contiguously in memory so fetching the nth element can be done in O(1) time.